# Upgrading Node.js

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, nodejs, curl

I'm currently installing Node.js on my system running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS I've run the commands from the website:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I'm just wondering if I were to run the apt-get without the curl command in the future to upgrade, would I still get the latest version? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the downloaded file:

```
wget https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x
```

and you will see the following lines at the end of the file:

```
print_status 'Creating apt sources list file for the NodeSource Node.js 5.x repo...'

exec_cmd "echo 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x ${DISTRO} main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
exec_cmd "echo 'deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x ${DISTRO} main' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list"
```

As you can see, the script creates a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/nodesource.list` with the content (eg. for wily)

```
deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x wily main
deb-src https://deb.nodesource.com/node_5.x wily main
```

This means that **you will get updates** with:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad you include the reasoning and how one would go about to find out. That's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're adding the NodeSource Node.js 5.x repo to your system.  Each time you update and upgrade, you'll get the newest version that is in that repository.

Though, I can't garuntee it will be the most current version, just the most current version in that repo.